# StringBuilder alternative for better memory allocation

Tags: java, string, jpa, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am using this StringBuilder in order to add content in a query:

```
Integer lastEntryInEntityId = 1;//acquired through another query
Integer tmpValueForEntityId;
Integer lastEntryInEntity2Id = 1;//acquired through another query

StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("insert 
into entity(column,column_1,column_2,column_3) values");
StringBuilder queryString2 = new StringBuilder("insert 
into entity2(column,column_1,column_2,column_3) values");

for(Object[] entityToCopy : entitiesToCopy){
    Entity entity= (Entity )entityToCopy[0];
    tmpValueForEntityId= lastEntryInEntityId ;
    queryString.append("("+ lastEntryInEntityId ++ +","+entity.getProperty()+","+entity[1]+","+entity.getProperty2()+"),");

    for(Entity2 entity2 : entity.getEntity2Collection()){
        queryString2.append("("+lastEntryInEntity2Id ++ +","+tmpValueForEntityId+","+entity.getProperty2()+","+entity.getProperty3()+"),");
    }
}
```

This code takes both too much time and memory. It actually throws an OutOfMemoryException on adding to the second StringBuilder after some time (when `entitiesToCopy` are too many).

**How else can I write this code in order to make it faster and use less memory?**

NOTE: A java 8 solution would be preferred.

NOTE 2: I use EntityManager.

Comment: consider using JDBC batch processing

Comment: Try using append always instead of + operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I executed a query every x iterations so that the query doesn't get too big. This solved my problem.

```
int count = 0;
for(Object[] entityToCopy : entitiesToCopy){
   Entity entity= (Entity )entityToCopy[0];
   tmpValueForEntityId= lastEntryInEntityId ;
   queryString.append("("+ lastEntryInEntityId ++ 
      +","+entity.getProperty()+","+entity[1]+","+entity.getProperty2()+"),");

    for(Entity2 entity2 : entity.getEntity2Collection()){
        queryString2.append("("+lastEntryInEntity2Id ++ 
  +","+tmpValueForEntityId+","+entity.getProperty2()+","+entity.getProperty3()+"),");
    }
   count++;
   if(count%2000 == 0 || entitiesToCopy.size() == count){
       em.executeQuery(queryString);
       queryString = "";
       em.executeQuery(queryString2);
       queryString2 = "";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `concat()` instead `+` inside `StringBuilder`

```
    for(Object[] entityToCopy : entitiesToCopy){
    Entity entity= (Entity )entityToCopy[0];
    tmpValueForEntityId= lastEntryInEntityId ;
    queryString.append("(").append(lastEntryInEntityId++).append(",").append(entity.getProperty()).append(",").append(entity[1]).append(",").append(entity.getProperty2()).append("),");

    for(Entity2 entity2 : entity.getEntity2Collection()){
        queryString2.append("(").append(lastEntryInEntity2Id ++).append(",").append(tmpValueForEntityId).append(",").append(entity.getProperty2()).append(",").append(entity.getProperty3()).append("),");
    }
}
```

---

For better performance, use `PreparedStatement` in transaction:

```
dbCon.setAutoCommit(false);
    var pst = dbCon.prepareStatement("insert into entity (columnID, column_1, column_2, column_3) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
for(Object[] entityToCopy : entitiesToCopy){
   var entity = (Entity )entityToCopy[0];
   tmpValueForEntityId = lastEntryInEntityId;
   pst.setInt(1, lastEntryInEntityId);
   pst.setString(2, entity.getProperty());
   pst.setString(3, entity[1]);
   pst.setString(4, entity.getProperty2());
   pst.addBatch();
}
pst.executeBatch();
dbCon.commit();
dbCon.setAutoCommit(true);
```

---

Each `?` represents a column. The first one represents the ID, the second one represents `column_1`, etc. Keep the order of each one.

Note: If you are using Java prior to 1.10, change `var` to `PreparedStatement`

---

With concurrent connections (more than one thread insert into database):

1. Don't close the database connection after commit (close on program exit)
2. The method that inserts data should be `synchronized`
3. Don't use `prepareStatement()`, instead use `createStatement()` with `Pattern` (regex) to avoid SQLinjections.

Note: `PreparedStatement` is good, fast and secure.

The database keep a pool of prepared statements to avoid create new every time. But in concurrence, after one thread have a reference to existing statement -> `PreparedStatement`, another thread can use it  and the transactioin is slow (waits for new instance or new reference to existing). In concurrence this happens many, many times.

---

EntityManager example:

```
    var em = emf.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = null;
try {
    transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    for(Object[] entityToCopy : entitiesToCopy){
         var entity = (Entity )entityToCopy[0];
         ...//insert here
    }

    tx.commit();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    if (transaction != null && transaction.isActive()) {
         tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
} finally {
    em.close();
}
```

Comment: I am using EntityManager, is batch processing possible?

Comment: Avoid stacking the code. Less is better. I never use EntityManager

Comment: Actually successive append method led to slower performance. Is it better with memory allocation?

Comment: StringBuilder .append is faster than +. https://kylewbanks.com/blog/java-string-concatenation-vs-stringbuilder-vs-string-format-performance